# How to remove the border of a QDialog which I give a transparent background image?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, transparent, borderless

I intended to make a un-rectangle `QDialog`, so I paint a png image by override `QDialog::paintEvent`.Everything is okay except there is a gray border shown arrond the dialog.Like this:

[image]

I am sure that border is not belong to the image,and I had `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` and `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true)`.I tried to set a qss like `border-width: 0px` but didn't work.
Is there any way to remove the border?And why it is shown?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a borderless dialog by setting `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` window flag :

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

To make it transparent you should set these attributes :

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
```

Comment: Thx for that.I will try it a few hours later.